# Optimize progressive computing of Datetime in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

[image]

In the picture I have this setup where I subtract the different datetime field of the next column. I have it done, but it slows down to the point that it time-out at 200k records. Please help me optimize my SQL query.

```
SELECT barcode,documents.document_title, routes.receive_at, routes.release_at,
SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(
        TIME_TO_SEC(
            timediff(
                receive_at, (SELECT
                                 release_at 
                               FROM 
                                 routes table12
                               WHERE DATE(routes.receive_at) between  "2021-10-01" AND "2021-10-18"  and routes.id < table12.id 
                            
                               ORDER BY 
                                 id ASC 
                               LIMIT 1
                              )
                    )
            ) 
    ) 
) as time_office,
  
  SEC_TO_TIME( 
    SUM( 
        TIME_TO_SEC( 
            timediff(
                receive_at, routes.release_at
            )
        )
    )
  ) as time_travel 
from routes 
LEFT JOIN documents on routes.barcode = documents.document_code
WHERE DATE(routes.receive_at) between "2021-10-01" AND "2021-10-18"
order by  routes.id ASC
```

Comment: *`WHERE DATE(routes.receive_at) between "2021-10-01" AND "2021-10-18"`* - replace with `WHERE routes.receive_at >= '2021-10-01' AND routes.receive_at < '2021-10-19'` (function in WHERE causes fullscan). Create index `routes(receive_at, barcode)` or `routes(barcode, receive_at)` (check in practice which of them provides more fast execution).

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has `LEAD()` and `LAG()`.